# Trouble freezing python script with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, cx-freeze, xlwings

I am having a lot of trouble freezing my program with cx_freeze. Any help would be appreciated. I have been successful when I freeze stuff that does not use numpy but I am having trouble with this on and it seems to have to do with numpy.

Here is the output when I try to run the exe.

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 27, in <module>
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "de_beams_xlw.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2284, in _handle_fromlist
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2212, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2284, in _handle_fromlist
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "ExtensionLoader_numpy_core_multiarray.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "ExtensionLoader_numpy_core_multiarray.py", line 14, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

And my setup file:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable


build_exe_options = {'packages': ['win32com', 'xlwings', 'numpy'],
                     'excludes': ['scipy', 'email', 'xml', 'pandas', 'Tkinter',
                                  'Tkconstants', 'pydoc', 'tcl', 'tk', 'matplotlib',
                                  'PIL', 'nose', 'setuptools', 'xlrd', 'xlwt', 'PyQt4',
                                  'markdown', 'IPython', 'docutils'],
                     'optimize': 2}


setup(name = 'de_beams_xlw',
      version = '0.1.0',
      options = {'build_exe': build_exe_options},
      executables = [Executable('de_beams_xlw.py', targetName="de_beams_xlw.exe")])
```

Comment: Can you post your setup.py file? That would help troubleshoot your problem.

Comment: @ schoolie Added, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up being a combination of package versions. Once I had the correct combination of packages it worked fine.